# MySQL Error with ASPCORE using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a data base with three tables. Users, messages and commits. The site boots up and I can login and register just fine When I go to post a message I am getting the following error.

> MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`thewall`.`messages`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fk_messages_users1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users`
>   (`UserId`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Looking up the error I know it has something to do with the many to 1 relation ship ie foreign key. But after looking at this and dumping the database 100 times. I need another pair of fresh eye to see if they can spot it.

MessageFactory.cs

```
public void Add(Message Item)
{
    using(IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
    {
        string Query = "INSERT INTO messages (MessageContent, PosterId, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt) VALUES (@MessageContent, @PosterId, NOW(), NOW())";
        dbConnection.Open();
        dbConnection.Execute(Query, Item);
    }
```

}

Table in question is setup like so

```
MessageId
MessageContent
PosterId
Createdat
Updatedat
user_id  <this is the foreign key> linking it to users.  


MessagesController.cs

 public IActionResult CreateMessage(Message model)
        {
            if(!CheckLogin())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("RegisterPage", "Users");
            }
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.PosterId = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("CurrUserId");
                _messageFactory.Add(model);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            List<Message> AllMessages = _messageFactory.GetAllMessages();
            ViewBag.CurrentUser = _userFactory.GetUserById((int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("CurrUserId"));
            ViewBag.Messages = AllMessages;
            return View("Index", model);
        }

Any help would be greatly appriacted.
```

Comment: The error message is right there the PosterId you are inserting into the messages table does not exist as a UserId in your User table

Comment: you're not setting parameter `@posterId`, so the query tries to insert `null` values for that parameter, something like `dbConnection.Execute(Query, Item, currentUserId)`

Comment: I am setting up the posterid  via the message controller